# Trigger function for each element in array and set new variables

Tags: javascript

In my application I define an array of objects and attachments for mailOptions

```
let products = [{product: 'product-184', id: 184, description: 'description for product-184'}, {product: 'product-192', id: 192, description: 'description for product-192'}, {product: 'product-122', id: 122, description: 'description for product-122'}]

mailOptions = {
                attachments: [
                    {
                        filename: `filename.csv`,
                        content: csvText
                    },
                ]
            };
```

I use a library to create CSV from the array of objects

```
csvText = mailCSV(products);
```

What I want to achieve now is to trigger this mailCSV function above for each element inside the array. If I send the whole array as a parameter it will create a CSV file based on all the elements so I need to find a way to trigger the function one by one and then store the data for each element inside new variables and then return those to the attachments part. Does anyone know any possibilities to do so?

I thought of something like this:

```
products.forEach(function (item, index) {
  csvText[i] = mailCSV(products[i]);
});
```

Which then creates
csvText1,
csvText2,
csvText3,
etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may make a new array to store your outputs.

```
csvText=[]
products.map(prod=>{
     csvText.push(mailCSV(prod))
}
```

Now your csvText array has your desired output.

Comment: csvText.append is not a function, isn't .append jquery?

Comment: @networkcore my bad Sorry, working to sets of languages confuses you sometimes.
It is push, lemme correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want that csvText is a string and not an array:

```
let products = [{product: 'product-184', id: 184, description: 'description for product-184'}, {product: 'product-192', id: 192, description: 'description for product-192'}, {product: 'product-122', id: 122, description: 'description for product-122'}]

let csvText = products.map((p) => mailCSV(p)).join('\n');
```

Assuming instead you want to use it as an array of strings:

```
let csvText = products.map((p) => mailCSV(p));
```

Answer (score -1):

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
csvText = products.map(mailCSV)
```